# Illustrator. What am I doing wrong when cutting a circle

Tags: adobe-illustrator, chart-design

I am a newbie in Illustrator. I was trying to get a donut chart with rounded end hoping this was easy. My target is the following picture:

[image]

What I did was to create a circle in blue, and over it a circle in black color. Then, this second one I cut it according to a certain angle as I was looking for a certain percentage (no matter for the moment). Then, rounding the ends, it should work, but what I get is this:
[image]

As you can see, it seems as if the ends were somehow connected, so in the black circle, there is an annoying effect I wish I could remove. Why is this happening? What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Create a circle with a stroke. Copy and Paste in front.

Select the top circle, select the Scissors Tool (C).

Click on the path where you want the end points of the line.

[image: example clicks]

Based on your example I first clicked at the top and then the bottom right. Delete this area.

Select the stroke, open your strokes panel (Window -> Stroke) and select the round cap icon.

[image: cap options]

Then select the bottom circle and color it a different color.

---

**Using Pie Graph Tool**

Select Pie Graph Tool (J), press anywhere on artboard, enter size.

Input data points, I did 3 | 7, hit apply (green check mark)

Select graph, remove fill and set stroke to desired size.

Select the Scissors Tool (C) and click the anchor points of where the data points meet. Then delete those points.

[image: scissors tool]

Do this again for the other side of the circle.

Use the Direct Select Tool to select one of the stroke and change its color.

Select all of the points and change them to round caps. Then go to Object -> Flatten Transparency and hit OK. Move the bottom stroke (mine was black) to the top.

[image: end result]